# Mongoose: properly getting the query result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

how are you? 
I'm quite new to mongoose and mongoDB and I'm having trouble doing a basic query. So, I have this code:

```
function addVoterToElection(req, res) {
    let query = Election.findOne({ 'name' : req.body.electionName });
    let result = query.exec((err, election) => {
        if(err) return err;
        return res.send(election);
    });
}
```

that works as intended, since t sends the election I need back to the requester:

```
{
    "_id": "594408b7c94fcdc009000001",
    "votechain": "594408b7c94fcdc009000002",
    "name": "eleicaoteste",
    "electionID": 12,
    "__v": 0,
    "voters": null
}
```

But the thing is that I need to use that object for other purposes, and I'm having trouble "extracting" it from the query.exec. If I do

```
let query = Election.findOne({ 'name' : req.body.electionName });
let result = query.exec((err, election) => {
    if(err) return err;
    return (election);
});
res.json(result);
```

all I get back is

```
{
    "emitted": {},
    "ended": false,
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 2
}
```

and thus I'm not able to use it for the next query that relies on having this election object working. What can I do? I know this is a fairly basic question, but I'm not sure I understand how the whole promise thing works.
Thank you so much!

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, I found that using the 'async' module, you can achieve the desired result as stated in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165153/4148031

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let query = Election.findOne({ 'name' : req.body.electionName });

let result = query.exec((err, election) => {
    if(err) return err;
    return (election);
});

res.json(result);
```

Query runs asynchronously (in the background), while the rest of your code executes. When query is done exec'ing, it executes the callback that takes err and election. When you're returning the result, it hasn't finished executing yet, hence your problem.

What you can do is move res.json to the body of your callback, like so:

```
let query = Election.findOne({ 'name' : req.body.electionName });

query.exec((err, election) => {
    if(err) return err;
        res.json(election);
});
```

Comment: What if I need to use the result from this callback (election) in another query? Is there a way to wait until the callback is executed to continue with code?

Comment: You could look into async/await but it's probably overkill for what you're trying to accomplish. And findOne() is not returning the result of your query, you just pass a callback into it that wraps around the result when it's ready. So if you want to wait for it to finish before executing the rest of the code, just put the rest of the code you want to execute afterwards in the success part of the callback. Like if (err) { console.log(err) } else { //...do rest of stuff  }. If you have a lot of nested callbacks you can look into promises, but I'd get familiar with using callbacks first!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using the `promise` right.

This is a good place to start learning about `Promises`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

The solution is very straightforward:

```
let query = Election.findOne({ 'name' : req.body.electionName });
let result = query.exec();

result.then((result) => {
    res.json(result);
}).catch((error) => {
    // console.log(err);
});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I ended up using the async module, but will keep that in mind!